# admob native ads integration in RecyclerView with firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to implement admob native ads in recyclerview with firebase database, but the items doesn't show correctly (some of them is missing), and also when ever i update the database the items disappear and the number of ads increase. this is my code:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String APPID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" ;
    private static final String ADSID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712" ;

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 5;
    // The AdLoader used to load ads.
    private AdLoader adLoader;

    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();

    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    //private List<Object> mArrayList ;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView ;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mRecyclerViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,APPID);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ITEMS");
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Fixture mFixture = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Fixture.class);
                    mRecyclerViewItems.add(mFixture);
                }
                mRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,mRecyclerViewItems);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tips Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadNativeAds();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
        if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        int offset = (mRecyclerViewItems.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
        int index = 0;
        for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : mNativeAds) {
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(index, ad);
            index = index + offset;
        }
    }

    private void loadNativeAds() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
                new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).withAdListener(
                new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                        // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                        Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                                + " load another.");
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();

        // Load the Native ads.
        adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mAdView != null) {
            mAdView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    // A menu item view type.
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    // An Activity's Context.
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;

    /**
     * For this example app, the recyclerViewItems list contains only
     * {@link MenuItem} and {@link UnifiedNativeAd} types.
     */
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Object> recyclerViewItems) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mRecyclerViewItems = recyclerViewItems;
    }

    /**
     * The {@link MenuItemViewHolder} class.
     * Provides a reference to each view in the menu item view.
     */
    public class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView item1;
        private TextView item2;
        private TextView item3;
        private TextView item4;
        private TextView item5;

        MenuItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            item1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            item2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            item3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item3);
            item4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item4);
            item5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerViewItems.size();
    }

    /**
     * Determines the view type for the given position.
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object recyclerViewItem = mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
        if (recyclerViewItem instanceof UnifiedNativeAd) {
            return UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
        return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new view for a menu item view or a Native ad view
     * based on the viewType. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
     */
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View unifiedNativeLayoutView;
                LayoutInflater inflaterNative = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                unifiedNativeLayoutView = inflaterNative.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified,viewGroup,false);
                return new UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(unifiedNativeLayoutView);
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                // Fall through.
            default:
                View menuItemLayoutView;
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                menuItemLayoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixture_row,viewGroup,false);
                return new MenuItemViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
                /*
                View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.fixture_row, viewGroup, false);
                return new MenuItemViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);*/
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the content in the views that make up the menu item view and the
     * Native ad view. This method is invoked by the layout manager.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (viewType) {
            case UNIFIED_NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd = (UnifiedNativeAd) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
                populateNativeAdView(nativeAd, ((UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder) holder).getAdView());
                break;
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                // fall through
            default:
                MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
                Fixture fixture = (Fixture) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

                // Add the menu item details to the menu item view.
                menuItemHolder.item1.setText(fixture.getItem1());
                menuItemHolder.item2.setText(fixture.getItem2());
                menuItemHolder.item3.setText(fixture.getItem3());
                menuItemHolder.item4.setText(fixture.getItem4());
                menuItemHolder.item5.setText(fixture.getItem5());
        }
    }

    private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd,
                                      UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
        // Some assets are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
        ((TextView) adView.getBodyView()).setText(nativeAd.getBody());
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());

        // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
        // check before trying to display them.
        NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();

        if (icon == null) {
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getPrice() == null) {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getPriceView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getPriceView()).setText(nativeAd.getPrice());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStore() == null) {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            adView.getStoreView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) adView.getStoreView()).setText(nativeAd.getStore());
        }

        if (nativeAd.getStarRating() == null) {
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((RatingBar) adView.getStarRatingView())
                    .setRating(nativeAd.getStarRating().floatValue());
            adView.getStarRatingView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Assign native ad object to the native view.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
    }
}
```

UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder.java

```
public class UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private UnifiedNativeAdView adView;

    public UnifiedNativeAdView getAdView() {
        return adView;
    }

    UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        adView = (UnifiedNativeAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

        // The MediaView will display a video asset if one is present in the ad, and the
        // first image asset otherwise.
        adView.setMediaView((MediaView) adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_media));
        // Register the view used for each individual asset.
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
        adView.setBodyView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_icon));
        adView.setPriceView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price));
        adView.setStarRatingView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars));
        adView.setStoreView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));
    }
}
```